# How is QoQ and YoY inflation calculated from data in the table below

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, inflation

[image]

I am confused about reference point for both QoQ and YoY. Is for Q1 is it (Q1 - 0)/0 * 100?

Comment: What does the table show? If so, you just combine the monthly change to show quarterly and the whole year. Monthly percent changes of price levels? Side remark; I assume you know that division by 0 is undefined.

Comment: @Alex I assume to calculate YoY and QoQ inflation you need to have data for previous year and same consecutive quarters months. Here values are monthly corresponding to years. Not sure how can you add them??